# 'dynamic' normalization

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Not too sure how I should properly describe the issue, but what I'm facing is the following. I have quite some whitespace content in files that was originally html. I want to remove this and the easiest way to deal with this is using an identity template and add the following

```
    <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Works fine, but a bit too well. Assume following example :

```
<p>    some content with whitespaces and a <a href="some_link">link</a> and some <strong>text</strong>
```

If I use the identity template my result of course 
looks like

```
 <p>some content with whitespaces and a<a href="some_link">link</a>and some<strong>text</strong>
```

but I'd like to preserve the whitespace in front of my a and strong tags (or basically any tag within a 'final' string. Since these content can be in quite some tags (divs, anchors, whatever) building exceptions might work but would become pretty complex as I would need to have a template-match loop for all tags that can live inside another one and add spaces again after initial cleanup.

Any easier way to approach this ?

Thanks in advance again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    if (starts-with(., ' ') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*]) then ' ' else '',
    normalize-space(.),
    if (ends-with(., ' ') and following-sibling::node()[1][self::*]) then ' ' else '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `[self::*]` predicate is achieving.  Will you explain this please?

Comment: `preceding-sibling::node()[1]` selects the first preceding sibling node which can be an element or a comment or processing instruction node. The predicate `[self::*]` checks it is an element node (and not a comment or processing instruction..

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*]">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::*]">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

When run with your sample XML produces:

```
so zacharyyoung$ xsltproc so.xsl so.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p>some content with whitespaces and a <a href="some_link">link</a> and some <strong>text</strong></p>
```

**Update 1**

True to Martin's question, this solution does introduce some unintended effects.  Given this input:

```
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>Text
  <p>    some content with whitespaces and a <a href="some_link">link</a> and some <strong>text</strong></p>
</div>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1> Text
  <p>some content with whitespaces and a <a href="some_link">link</a> and some <strong>text</strong></p>
</div>
```

So this is *not* a general-case solution.

Comment: Thanks Zach, works like a charm ! Other solutions provided might also work, but this one is a bit easier for me to understand.

Comment: @Wokoman: Thanks, though I'm concerned because Michael and Martin both know way more about XSLT than me, and they both are using the extra `[self::*]` predicate which I'm still trying to understand.  Please let me know if this solution is not all encompassing.

Comment: Doesn't this approach insert spaces at places where there weren't any in the original e.g. in `<div><h1>heading<h1>Text</div>` you would get `<div><h1>heading<h1> Text</div>`? And comment and processing instructions as sibling would also result in spaces being added.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Yes, it does have those unintended effects.  I'm going to leave my answer up as is because it satifies the OP's original question.

Comment: @all Fair points, I noticed myself in the meantime the above solution indeed has some side effects when not all strings are 'encapsulated' as shown in above example. So even when it removes excessive whitespace it leaves a few where it shouldn't be. I'll play a bit with the other options to see if it makes sense to upgrade to these. (but have to admit my brain hurts a bit when I look at them :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*]) and not(following-sibling::node()[1][self::*])]">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

plus

```
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*] and not(following-sibling::node()[1][self::*])">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+$', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*]) and following-sibling::node()[1][self::*]">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```